# expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, networking

I am trying to modelize a convolution using Tensorflow, in order to modelize an amplificator. Here is my code :

```
h = np.array([1,0.5,0.3,0.4])
t = np.linspace(0,10,50)
x = np.cos(t)
y = sc.convolve(h,x)[:len(t)]

length = len(h)

def memory_list_real(x, length):
"""Renvoie une liste des valeurs de x réelles mémorisées."""
list_x = []
for i in range(length, len(x)+1):
    list_x.append(x[i-length:i])
return list_x

def generate_real_model(length):
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = length, activation = 'linear'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
#Calcul de l'erreur
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() 
#Fonction d'optimisation (algorithme Adam)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
#Calcul de l'évolution de l'erreur
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="train_loss")
return model

@tf.function
def predict(x):
    return model(x)

@tf.function
def train_step(x, target):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        prediction = model(x)
        loss = loss(target, prediction)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_loss(loss)

x_test = memory_list_real(x, length)[:-1]
target = y

model = generate_real_model(length)

for epoch in range(5):
    for i in range(len(x_test)):
        train_step(x_test[i].T, target[i].T)
    print("Loss : %s", train_loss.results())
```

And i got the following error message :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_25 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4,)
```

Can you help me ? I tryed to change the shape of my data, but I don't know how to handle this error, because I am don't really control all the subtilities of Tensorflow^^

Thank you !

Comment: First of all, you should define the input shape, in your first layer. After that, you should pass the data as (samples or batch, data shape). So, the input data has 2 dimensions at least.

Comment: ok thanks I found the solution !

Comment: What's the solution?